# Scatter line - lastly plotted point stuck to y axis or x axis, how to give buffer around it?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Scatter line - lastly plotted point stuck to y axis or x axis, how to give buffer around it?
I have masked in this picture here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIUke.png)

Ref http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/scatter-line

I can provide few dummy points but I would like to know out of the box method.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
panes: [{
     clip: false
}]
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/XjNGAr)**

Comment: Thanks ezanker I am planning to scan all my x axis entries and modify 'max' . 'clip: false' did add little space but that is not quite good for me.